# c++ postfix evaluation problems

Tags: c++, c++11, postfix-notation

```
stack<int> s;
int main() {
    string exp;
    cout << "Enter postfix expression: ";
    getline(cin, exp);
    int calc = evaluatePosfix(exp);
    cout << calc << endl;
}

int evaluatePosfix(string exp) {
    for (int i = 0; i < exp.length(); i++) {
        if (exp[i] == ' ' || exp[i] == ',') {
            continue;
        }
        if (isNum(exp[i])){
            int operand = 0;
            while(i < exp.length() && isNum(exp[i])) {
                operand = (operand*10) + (exp[i] - '0');
                i++;
            }
            i--;
            cout << operand << "&&" << endl;
            s.push(operand);
        }

        else if(isOperator(exp[i])) {
            int operand2 = s.top(); s.pop();
            int operand1 = s.top(); s.pop();
            int result = performOperation(operand1, operand2, exp[i]);
            s.push(result);
        }

        //cout << s.top() << " $$$" << endl;
    }

    return s.top();
}

bool isOperator(char c) {
    if (c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool isNum(char c) {
    if (c >= '0' || c <= '9') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int performOperation(int operand1, int operand2, char operation) {
    if (operation == '+') {
        return operand1 + operand2;
    }
    else if (operation == '-') {
        return operand1 + operand2;
    }
    else if (operation == '*') {
        return operand1 * operand2;
    }
    else if (operation == '/') {
        return operand1 / operand2;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Post-fix is not being evaluated properly. When I type in 22+ it returns 215 instead of 4. When the program detects an operator, it should pop the 2 elements in the stack but for some reason it doesn't do that. When the performOperation is called, the operation does not occur, therefor nothing gets pushed onto the stack.

Answer (score 1):

If `22+` is supposed to evaluate to `4` then this section is the culprit:

```
while(i < exp.length() && isNum(exp[i])) {
    operand = (operand*10) + (exp[i] - '0');
    i++;
}
```

Your code is written to handle numbers greater than 10 but your example suggests that you only support single digits.

Answer (score 0):

@meat is correct you need to read the input stream (file or cin) as tokens.

```
#include <cstring>
char token[6];

while (stream >> token)
{
    if (token[0] == '=') // what ever the end char is
    {
        //process and evaluate expression
    }
    else if (isdigit(*token)) // will pass a 4 byte int not just 0-9
    {
        // process a number
    }
    else if (ispunct(token0])) // is 1 byte math symbol + - * / 
    {
        // process a math symbol
    }
```

that should solve the 0-9 reading issues.